# Routing a HV pulse across a number of channels

Tags: high-voltage

I have a number N of loads ranging between 3 and 16 (In the schematic I only draw 3 to avoid bloat) that requires well-timed high voltage pulses. The pulses have a width of 20~50 us and a period of 150 us

Instead of having separate pulse generators for each load, I would like to share the same generator circuit with all the loads, and send every pulse on sequence across the loads (so that every N pulses, the pulse is sent back to the first load)

What would be a reasonable way to route the pulses across the sequence of loads?

[image: HV pulse router]

Comment: Automotive distributors (single coil variety) use a non-contact mechanical switch to distribute the spark to individual spark plugs. You want something electronic? 4kV is a fairly high voltage for an electronic switch, but not impossible.

Comment: How well preserved must the waveshape be? what risetime **Must** you provide? what ringing to tolerate?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf risetime up to 5 us are acceptable, I was hoping to address any ringing with a critically damped RLC pass

Comment: @SpehroPefhany something without movable parts would be preferred of course, I was researching into thyratrons for this purpose, but still unclear how to apply them here. The distributor idea sounds reasonable but I was wondering what other options would be there

Comment: 15A 3.5kV 33% duty cycle > 50 kW pulse generator =  unfeasible concept,   with what budget? and no experience

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a tetrode to control the thyratron

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faFnDh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
might need a capacitr between thyratron gate and input to compensate fro the tetrode capacitance,

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? Confirm if I understand your concept correctly: you are suggesting to use a custom designed thyratron with multiple anodes, and add an additional leg with a voltage that shifts/selects which anode the thyratron current should target? I don't see how the pulses are sent through the multiple load outputs on this diagram